# Blender 4.0 error on startup "AttributeError: 'bpy.app' object has no attribute 'version_char'"

Tags: add-on, error

Updated to 4.0, everything was great, but when I open a specific project from the previous version (which i guess is 3.6.5), it just crashes. managed to get a screenshot of the system console:
[image: system console]
it references a font called "consolaz" which i've never heard of. I have text objects in that project that uses the font *consolas*, which is built into windows, so it shouldn't be missing.
heres what the crash log put:

[image: crash log]

It also mentioned some addons, I tried removing the ones listed and nothing changed.
I have an Nvidia RTX 2060 super, if that helps. I cannot attach the blend file itself, as its quite proprietary and I haven't managed to isolate and replicate the issue on any other files.
I downloaded and imported the custom font "DejaVuSans" as the interface font because I didn't prefer the new default one, but I dont know why that would interfere with anything.

EDIT: added text for the startup console errors:

```
Read prefs: "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\config\userpref.blend"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 364, in enable
    mod = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "H:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from . import mixamo_rig
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\mixamo_rig.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .utils import *
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .lib.bones_pose import *
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\lib\bones_pose.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .version import *
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\lib\version.py", line 3, in <module>
    class ARP_blender_version:
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\lib\version.py", line 7, in ARP_blender_version
    _char = bpy.app.version_char
AttributeError: 'bpy.app' object has no attribute 'version_char'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "H:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "H:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "H:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "H:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "H:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\python\lib\runpy.py", line 288, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "H:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\python\lib\runpy.py", line 252, in _get_code_from_file
    with io.open_code(decoded_path) as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'H:\\SteamLibrary\\steamapps\\common\\Blender\\<blender string>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 364, in enable
    mod = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "H:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\4.0\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from . import mixamo_rig
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\mixamo_rig.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .utils import *
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .lib.bones_pose import *
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\lib\bones_pose.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .version import *
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\lib\version.py", line 3, in <module>
    class ARP_blender_version:
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\lib\version.py", line 7, in ARP_blender_version
    _char = bpy.app.version_char
AttributeError: 'bpy.app' object has no attribute 'version_char'
```

Comment: Hello ! Go to the path mentioned in the error and delete the folder named AI-Render. Also there seems to be previous errors, they might all be caused by the first error that occurred, please also post AS TEXT, not screenshot, the first error that pops up in the stack

Comment: @Gorgious Deleted AI render, no difference. added the other errors

Comment: The addons you're using are calling a deprecated member of `bpy.app`. It was removed in 4.0. See https://docs.blender.org/api/3.6/bpy.app.html#bpy.app.version_char for 3.6 and https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.html#bpy.app.version_char for 4.0 where it was removed. https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Python_API for the release note. Either download the addon latest version, ask the addon developer to update it, disable the addons or revert back to Blender 3.6